# How to make a material-ui Modal scrollable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've created a `Modal` and put some text in it describing my app and how to use it, but the text overflows the `Modal` and so the top and bottom of the text aren't visible. I'd like to make the component scrollable so that my text isn't running off the ends of the page.

```
// The styling for the modal
const styles = theme => ({
    paper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: theme.spacing.unit * 130,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
    },
});


function getModalStyle() {
    const top = 50
    const left = 50

    return {
        top: `${top}%`,
        left: `${left}%`,
        transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
        overflow: "scroll"
    };
}
// The actual modal
<Modal
    aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
    aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
    open={this.state.modalOpen}
    onClose={this.handleModalClose}
>
    <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
        <MyLongTextComponent/>
    </div>
</Modal>
```

I'd like for this to have scroll functionality that's independent of the actual page behind it. I haven't found much help on the internet, so any pointers would be very helpful! Also, if a `Modal` is the wrong component to use in this situation, please let me know. I'm moderately new to React and material-ui, so if there's a better way I'd love to learn how.

Comment: Will be better if you can create stackblitz demo

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to use 'overflow = scroll' for modal style.

Below is example code to get scrollable material-ui modal. withStyles is used to apply style for modal in this example.

- [image example of material-ui scrollable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXjS1.png)
- [material-ui usage of withstyles](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#api)

  ```
  const styles = theme => ({
    modalStyle1:{
      position:'absolute',
      top:'10%',
      left:'10%',
      overflow:'scroll',
      height:'100%',
      display:'block'
    }
  });
  <Modal open={this.state.open4} className={this.props.classes.modalStyle1}>
    <div>
      <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={this.closeOrder}>
        Close
      </Button>
      {this.getPics()}
    </div>
  </Modal>
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much! This led me down the right track to fix the problem.

Comment: @JahzielVillasana Glad this led you to a solution, but just FYI I've now updated the [documentation for Modal](https://material-ui.com/utils/modal/) to make it clear that [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/) is generally what you want as a starting point for modal dialogs rather than Modal so that you don't reinvent solutions (for things like having scrollable content) that are already solved out-of-the-box with Dialog.

Comment: In my case, `display: "block"` was the key. That fixed it like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

You will have better luck using the Dialog component. Modal is a lower-level construct which Dialog leverages. You can find Dialog examples in the component demos section.

Comment: Thanks! I started with Backdrop and was really struggling to make it work. Didn't realize that Dialog was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I  know this question had already been answered but I found the checked reply as not complete.

In order to make a proper Modal you will most likely want it to have a max height and to be divided in 3 main sections:

- Header
- Content
- Footer (optional)

If you have a long list of element in the content (i.e. a form), setting `overflow: 'scroll'` to `modal` will lead to two main issues:

- `maxHeight` will only be applied to container while the rest of the content will be still visible underneath
- When the user will scroll, the header will also scroll out of sight

A closer-to-production example involving only header and content would then be:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  modal:{
    position:'absolute',
    top:'10%',
    left:'10%',
    overflow:'hidden',
    height:'100%',
    maxHeight: 500,
    display:'block'
  },
  header: {
    padding: '12px 0',
    borderBottom: '1px solid darkgrey'
  },
  content: {
    padding: 12,
    overflow: 'scroll'
  }
});

const { classes } = this.props
<Modal open={this.state.open}>
  <div className={classes.modal}>
    <div className={classes.heading}>
      <h4>Your Title here</h4>
    </div>

    <div className={classes.content}>
      <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={this.closeOrder}>
        Close
      </Button>

      {this.getPics()}
    </div>    
  </div>
</Modal>
```

Beside being better formatted, this solution has also two main differences that solve the real-life issues explained above:

- Modal has `overflow: hidden`, hiding everything outside its box
- Content has `overflow: scroll`, which doesn't skyrocket the header away and it's what we are looking for

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

From the v5 docs, you want to use a `Dialog` instead of a `Modal` which has a `scroll=body|paper` prop.

Instead of using a modal with an `overflow:auto` with an enclosing `<div/>`:

```
<Modal open={contentOpened} style={{ overflow: "auto" }}>
  <div>
    <MyModalContent />
  </div>
</Modal>
```

use the cleaner `<Dialog/>`

```
<Dialog open={contentOpened} scroll="body">
  <MyModalContent />
</Dialog>
```

Read more on MUI scrolling-content dialogs [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#scrolling-long-content)...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a quick answer to this, here's the solution I found:

```
<Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
                style={{ overflow: 'scroll' }}
              >

       <div style={
       zIndex: 10,
       position: absolute,}>
{/*your content here*/}
       </div>

</Modal>
```

So only 2 simple steps...

1. Make modal overflow scrollable

   ```
   <Modal
                style={{ overflow: 'scroll' }}
              >
   ```
2. Update styles for every direct child of the modal. You need to add these 2 attributes at least:

   ```
   <div style={
   zIndex: 10,
   position: absolute,}>
   ```

Then you can use css to reposition the content with the `top` or `left` properties, or customize the container as you want. **No need to switch to the Dialog component to solve this.**

Comment: This is the best quick answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `disableScrollLock` prop:

```
<Modal disableScrollLock={true}>
</Modal>
```

By default it is set to false.

All available props are documented [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/)